# Dropdown menu unfocused

Tags: css

It's not a new problem - when you hover over the dropdown menu, it disappears. I searched many topics and I know about child and sibling selectors, but I still can't find my mistake in my code.

Here's my code and a demo:

```
.navbar ul {
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.navbar ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 28px 0 0;
vertical-align:top;
}

.navbar ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar ul > li > a:after {
    content: "|";
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar ul > li:last-child a:after {
    content: "";
}

/* DROPDOWN LIST */

    .navbar ul ul {
    position: absolute;
      margin: 19px 0 0 0;
      padding: 0;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 355px;
      background-color: #00e1f5;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xKM2/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the top margin from the submenu. That will leave you some other issues but that's the cause. With the margin, there is a gap so when you move the mouse down...you are no longer hovering the parent `li`. http://jsfiddle.net/5xKM2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you mentioned is because you have a 19px margin between your dropdown and the li.

remove it and add padding to navbar > ul  > li to fix it.

```
.navbar > ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 28px 0 0;
  padding: 19px 0;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.navbar ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 355px;
    background-color: #00e1f5;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taxellool/93ZEm/)

and yes the triangle is not there anymore. I actually didn't try to fix it cause this menu has lots of serious issues and I think you need to rethink the whole structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you reference me to good examples of menus with dropdown?